# Como definir os 100% da altura entre uma navbar e uma div (responsivo)

Tags: html, css, height

Estou tendo dificuldade em definir a altura de um conteúdo html, com o css e bootstrap. Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação web em quero ter um mapa que ocupa quase a tela toda. O mapa irá dividir os 100% da tela com um menu suspenso, uma navbar fixa. Logo apos essa navbar quero ter um mapa que ocupe o restante da tela, até o final, sem aparecer a barra de rolagem. Preciso também fazer isso de forma responsiva, em todos os tipos de telas esse conteúdo(mapa) se adapte na altura.
Estou fazendo teste e com o que acho na internet, mas nada ainda conseguiu resolver meu problema. Alguém consegue me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veja como fiz:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
div#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div#container #topo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 0;
}
div#container #mapa {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Teste</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <nav id="topo" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
          </form>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
                </li>
                <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <div id="mapa">
      <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.in/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=+&amp;q=surat&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Surat,+Gujarat&amp;ll=21.195,72.819444&amp;spn=0.36299,0.676346&amp;t=m&amp;z=11&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu precisava. Me ajudou muito. Obrigado!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou! Abraço!